# Magento 2 : Google Customer Reviews

Tags: magento2, review, code-generation

How will final result should look like for this implementation. 
Thank you

file location: `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php`

Below is my default `Success.php` for Magento 2.1

```
<?php /**  *  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */ namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage {
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator')->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    } }
```

............................ where do i paste this code on Success.php

> `<script>
>     window.renderOptIn = function() {
>       window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
>         window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
>           {
>             "merchant_id": XXXXXXXXX,
>             "order_id": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>",
>             "email": "<?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>",
>             "delivery_country": "<?php echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() ?>",
>             "estimated_delivery_date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
>           });
>       });
>   }
>   </script>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you would use the file located at or whatever the **vendor/template** you use

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
```

In which case, you would put the google code after the last  in the **success.phtml** file

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this code in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
            <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?= $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action primary continue" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getContinueUrl() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.renderOptIn = function() {
        window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
            window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
            {
                "merchant_id": XXXXXXXXX,
                "order_id": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>",
                "email": "<?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>",
                "delivery_country": "<?php echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() ?>",
                "estimated_delivery_date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/magento/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

Add this script

```
<script>

  window.renderOptIn = function() {

  window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {

  window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(

    {

      "merchant_id": xxxxxxxxx,

      "order_id": "<?php echo $orderData->getIncrementId() ?>",

      "email": "<?php echo $orderData->getCustomerEmail() ?>",

      "delivery_country": "<?php echo $orderData->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() ?>",

      "estimated_delivery_date": "YYYY-MM-DD"

    });

 });

 }

</script>
```

Comment: This looks like code for Magento 1, not Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

How about the GTIN for products review?

```
     "products":[{"gtin":"GTIN1"}, {"gtin":"GTIN2">}],
```

Anyone can help to retrieve the "barcode" of the items ordered?

I can retrieve the SKU with this code:

```
public function getGtinProducts() {
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $products = [];
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $product) {
        $gtin = ["gtin" => $product->getSku()];
        $products[] = (object)$gtin;
    }
    return json_encode($products);
}
```

But I need to retrieve the barcode attribute instead SKU. Any idea how to?

Comment: create a text attribute to product and than get it. 
$prdObj = $this->productLoader->create()->load($product->getData('product_id'));
            $gtin = ['gtin' => $prdObj->getBarcode()];