# How to setup Google Customer Reviews in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Below is my code-

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
<?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
    <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
        <p><?= __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
    <?php  else :?>
        <p><?= __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
        <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
<?= $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <a class="action primary continue" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getContinueUrl() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>

<script>
window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
        window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
            {
                // REQUIRED FIELDS
                "merchant_id": xxxxxx,
                "order_id": "<?= $data['orderid']; ?>",
                "email": "<?= $data['email']; ?>",
                "delivery_country": "<?= $data['country_id']; ?>",
                "estimated_delivery_date": "<?= $data['delivery_date']; ?>",

                // OPTIONAL FIELDS
                "products": [{"gtin":"GTIN1"}, {"gtin":"GTIN2"}]
            });
    });
}
```

I based it off of [Cross-origin problem: Google Customer Reviews is not displaying on success page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171189/cross-origin-problem-google-customer-reviews-is-not-displaying-on-success-page/171275)

And I get this error- Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: data in /chroot/home/html/app/design/frontend/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml on line 36

At the bottom I changed it out to this-

```
         "merchant_id": xxxxx,
         "order_id": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>",
         "email": "<?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>",
         "delivery_country": "<?php echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() ?>",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
```

Based on [Magento 2 : Google Customer Reviews](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167643/magento-2-google-customer-reviews)

I get the same error. What is the proper code?

Comment: Please add before script `<?= $data = $block->getOrderId(); ?>` and try.

Comment: @Pawan Should I use the first or second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer below Magento 2 Google Customer Reviews extension.

https://github.com/aleksandar-babic/magento2-GCR

Comment: That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code after default code of phtml.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $data = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
    $billinAdress = $data->getBillingAddress(); //you can also use shipping address

?>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>

<script>
window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
        window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
            {
                // REQUIRED FIELDS
                "merchant_id": xxxxxx,
                "order_id": "<?php echo $data->getId(); ?>",
                "email": "<?php echo $data->getCustomerEmail();?>",
                "delivery_country": "<?php echo $billinAdress->getCountryId();?>",
                "estimated_delivery_date": "<?php echo $data->getCreatedAt(); ?>",

                // OPTIONAL FIELDS
                "products": [{"gtin":"GTIN1"}, {"gtin":"GTIN2"}]
            });
    });
}
```

on front you will get result something like in console:

[image]

**Notes:**

1. You can also use increment Id in above code
2. You can also use Shipping address for country Id
3. For estimated delivery date, I used order created date. You need to change it.
4. **Most Important** I have used `objectManager` in above code, once yo got working code as per your requirement, Please use Dependency instead of `objectManager`

Comment: I tried multiple times with this and could never get it going. There were a few spelling errors that I fixed but even after that I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

There is free [Google customer reviews extension by Aitoc](https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-google-customer-reviews.html), you can also check its work on their demo.

Comment: I don't found free module but you can check paid module of MageAnts [Magento 2 Google Customer Review](https://www.mageants.com/google-customer-review-for-magento-2.html) will surely help